# ApacheBench is very slow

Tags: php, benchmarking, slim, apachebench, silex

I have created two benchmark pages using Slim and Silex micro frameworks, then tested them for speed.

**Chrome Developer Tools result:**

Slim: 7ms

Silex: 16ms

**ApacheBench result:**

```
# Slim
$ ab -n 1 -c 1 'http://localhost/webapps/FrameworksBenchmarking/Slim/data/123'
> 5.008 seconds

# Silex
ab -n 1 -c 1 'http://localhost/webapps/FrameworksBenchmarking/Silex/data/123'
> 0.001 seconds
```

I don't understand what makes `ab` so slow with Slim. Any ideas on this issue?

PS as you can see, there's no problem requesting page in browser. Also, it's fast with `curl`.

Comment: Setup a [profiler](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) and find out

Comment: it's caused by `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");` in Response object. Strange...

Comment: Dunno why you were downvoted, I'm seeing this too. Very strange.

Comment: @Roman why do you say it's caused by the header?

Comment: Edited: In the light of this post, I tried it on a page that has custom PHP written by me. In Chrome, it took about 12ms and with apachebench, it took about 3.325 ms. Anyone can explain that? Or can anyone suggest a way to help me dig into this coz' I am new to this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use PHP Accelerator? Have you warmed up everything before benchmarking? -n 1 -c 1 doesn't seem sufficient to provide any accurate statistics. Try to increase a number of repetitions.

Comment: Yes, I use APC. -n 1 -c 1 is accurate enough as I run it multiple times and changing these parameters to greater values makes it much more slower.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set HTTP version to 1.0 for [Slim App](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/application.html):

```
$app = new \Slim\App(['settings' => ['httpVersion'=>'1.0']]);
```

---

It seems like ab test has a bug for the PHP header code:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
exit;
```